# understanding code for removing duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around why this code works to remove dupilcates.

```
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    if (!nums.length) return 0
    let j = 0;
    for (let i=0; i< nums.length; i++) {
       if ( nums[i] !== nums[j] ) {
           j++;
           nums[j] = nums[i]
       }
    }
    return j + 1
};
```

I am playing around on leetcode and this was my answer.

```
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    let isDuplicates = true
    let counter = 0
    while (isDuplicates) {
        isDuplicates = false
        for (let i=0; i<= nums.length - counter; i++){
            helper(nums, i, i+1)
            isDuplicates = true
        }
        counter++ 
    }
    return nums.length
};
function helper(array, i, j){
if (array[i] === array[j]) array.splice(i, 1);

}
```

I came across the first code looking through other solutions, I am trying to improve and grasp the details. I realize my helper probably is not optimal, but I am playing around and learning. Thanks for everyones time!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: It doesn't look like that function actually does remove dupes from an array.

Comment: They took two positions on the sorted array, and started comparing the values at two positions and start sliding `i` towards the end of the array if the data is duplicate without doing anything, while keeping the `j` at the same position, when they find next non duplicate character they just increased `j`'s value by one and add the new value at that position. One thing they forgot to `splice` the remaining values once the loop is over, I think that's why they are returning `j+1`, so to initialize the length of the array to that value.

Comment: Christian, my question is why the first code works to remove duplicates, though Gaurav Singh has clarified everything for me. Thank you everyone. I appreciate the responses!

Comment: I'm glad I wasn't crazy in thinking that it does not remove duplicates. The original question on leetcode was to return the length after all duplicates were removed but my brain was stuck on duplicates removed. Did not even think about the j+1 being enough to satisfy the requirement.

Comment: Only works if the array is sorted